# Set series color

Tags: jquery, flot

How to set colors of all series in flot as same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're providing the data, give them the same [`color` property or index](http://turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/ToscaWidgets/Cookbook/Flot.html).

For example:

```
[ { color: 0, label: "Foo", data: [ [10, 1], [17, -14], [30, 5] ] },
  { color: 0, label: "Bar", data: [ [11, 13], [19, 11], [30, -7] ] } ]
```

In  this case they'd both get color #0 in the auto-generated color array Flot has.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an array of colors in the options as well:

```
$.plot($("#plot"), [plotData], { colors: ['#0000FF'] });
```